# ImportError: cannot import name 'is_scalar' in Python 3.6 Virtual environment

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, matplotlib-basemap

I have created a virtual environment for python 3.6. As stated in the matplotlib/basecamp GitHub [repository](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap), I have installed basemap through the command -

```
pip install --user git+https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap.git
```

When I try to import basemap like so,

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

I get the error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_scalar'
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in the [matplotlib Basemap Github Issues](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/439#issuecomment-436759980).

> It looks like you have an older version of basemap. This has already been fixed and is in the released version v1.2.0.
>
> Some notes: basemap is considered deprecated in favor of the cartopy package. Please learn cartopy instead. Second, the preferred method of installing basemap (or cartopy) is through conda-forge due to its complex build process and dependencies.

Comment: I have gone through this link. I have the latest version. The command through which I installed, gets the latest version. Yep, I have given up on Basemap and will be using Folium instead. Check this out if you are interested - https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#GeoJSON/TopoJSON-Overlays

Comment: If you are determined to use this deprecated library, I would strongly recommend installing it in the recommended way. This is likely to resolve your issue